# UIAlertView after MOC background save works iOS 7 not iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, parent-child, uialertview

I have a parent detail view controller that provides common custom functions to child detail views.

The parent includes two custom functions.

One function triggers a background save to two `NSManagedObjectContext`s that saves a main MOC immediately to free up UI, then saves a private MOC. Fairly standard setup pre iOS 8.

The following function presents a `UIAlertView` to confirm the save was successful. This includes code to automatically dismiss after a set amount of time (about half a second).

This all works fine running iOS 7, both on device and on simulator.

This causes a crash when running iOS 8, both on device and on simulator.

The problem exists for only one of the five child detail views. Following a detailed side by side comparison I confirm that these each have identical code blocks and methods.

I have break points inserted into the two custom functions. The save works fine, but the code crashes after trying to present the `UIAlertView`, as mentioned only when running iOS 8. The debugger steps into machine code that I do not understand. The attempted save does not persist.

If I comment out the alert view, the save persists, but obviously I no longer have the alert view for the user.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Think I may have found a solution... of sorts... not definite yet...

`UIAlertController` and this article by [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/)

Comment: without the code its difficult to give a proper answer. but it sounds as if its not getting displayed on the main thread. personally i wouldn't show alert for saving. it will kinda be nagging constantly popping up a message even the user know if he presses save it will save.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The code in this case is irrelevant if you understand the concept and context of the question and in the case that you have experienced a similar issue. I could insert the code, but the relevant code is extensive. The UI is acting on the main thread. I use a private and a main MOC that is created in my core data stack. I don't use multi-threading elsewhere in my code. As mentioned, this problem is only for one of five almost identical child view controllers, which all run on the main thread.

Comment: the private MOC runs in other thread than main. the crash could also happen if a view controller shows an alert view but controller gets released before alert view whose delegate is the controller.

Comment: Thank you for your comments however they do not make sense to me. When I write "don't use multi-threading elsewhere" those words imply that I acknowledge the private MOC is on thread other than main and multi-threading is not used anywhere else in any part of my code. Thanks for your suggestion but by its nature an alert view hijacks the screen and as my view and its controller are released by the user tapping the back button, then it being released before alert view is not digitally possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Augmenting the UIAlertView code in my parent detail view controller resolves the problem.

Within my `message` method I now check whether iOS responds to the `UIAlertController` class, and if it does instantiate a `UIAlertController`, otherwise instantiate a `UIAlertView`.

```
- (void)message {

    ...other code...

    if ([UIAlertController class]) {    //checking whether iOS responds to the UIAlertController class
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:titleComplete
                                                                   message:messageComplete
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion: ^(void){
            [self performSelector:(@selector(dismissAlertController:)) withObject:alert afterDelay:durationMessageCompleteSave];
        }];
    //  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    //  display time on screen too short using just the dismissViewController above, 
    //  so add into completion handler in call to presentViewController...

    } else {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:titleComplete
                                                        message:messageComplete
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil//self.localisedAlertButtonRemain
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];//buttonOther, nil];

        [alertView setTag:010];
        [alertView show];
        [self performSelector:(@selector(dismissAlertView:)) withObject:alertView afterDelay:durationMessageCompleteSave];

    }
}

...

- (void)dismissAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alert {
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
}

- (void)dismissAlertController:(UIAlertController *)alert {
    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```